# Realm android custom variable not preserved

Tags: android, realm

i'm a beginner in realm android but i'm a bit confused regarding RealmObject instance , i want to set a value in my @ignore variable with a setter but this is not preserved when i want to retrieve it with its getter function.
The object seams to not be the same.

Does this is not pass by reference? I really don't understand why it's be to not be the same object...

adapter of list of items on which i want ot affect a value in

```
list_equipement_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                Equipement equipement = equipementAdapter.getItem(position);


                Log.d("DEBUG_QT_EQUP","4 equipement:"+equipement.toString());
                Log.d("DEBUG_QT_EQUP","4 nombre_a_ajouter_dans_modele:"+equipement.getNb_chosen_for_modele());

                panelQuantityEquipement.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                panelQuantityEquipement.feedData(equipement, current_vaisseau_choix, realm);

                //Log.d("LUDOTEST", "onItemClick vaisseau: " + vaisseau.getNom_vas());
            }
        });
```

feedData function:
i store an Equipement object reference in this function

```
public void feedData(Equipement equipement1,Vaisseau vaisseau1,Realm realm1){

    this.equipement = equipement1;
    this.vaisseau = vaisseau1;
    this.realm = realm1;

    equipement_name.setText(equipement.getNom_equ());

    createSpinner();
}
```

createSpinner function:
when i click on item i set a value in Equipement object but when i click a second time on it the value setted is not preserve...

```
private void createSpinner(){

    nombre_a_ajouter_dans_modele = equipement.getNb_chosen_for_modele();
    Log.d("DEBUG_QT_EQUP","1 equipement:"+equipement.toString());
    Log.d("DEBUG_QT_EQUP","1 nombre_a_ajouter_dans_modele:"+nombre_a_ajouter_dans_modele);
    nb_max_case_dispo = vaisseau.getCase_placement_vas();
    int nb_max_case_dispo_pour_cet_equip = (int) Math.floor((double)nb_max_case_dispo/(double)equipement.getCase_required_equ());

    //spinner nombre affecté dans la création de la futur flotte
    ArrayList<String> nb_vso = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= nb_max_case_dispo_pour_cet_equip; i++) {
        nb_vso.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,nb_vso);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner_equipement_added.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner_equipement_added.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {

            nombre_a_ajouter_dans_modele = Integer.valueOf(spinner_equipement_added.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
            equipement.setNb_chosen_for_modele(nombre_a_ajouter_dans_modele);


            Log.d("DEBUG_QT_EQUP","2 nombre_a_ajouter_dans_modele:"+nombre_a_ajouter_dans_modele);

            Log.d("DEBUG_QT_EQUP","3 equipement:"+equipement.toString());
            Log.d("DEBUG_QT_EQUP","3 nombre_a_ajouter_dans_modele:"+equipement.getNb_chosen_for_modele());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Another interface callback
        }
    });

    spinner_equipement_added.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(String.valueOf(nombre_a_ajouter_dans_modele)));

}
```

Comment: `RealmResults.get(i)` returns a new instance of the proxy each time.

Comment: i call query only once
    
            equipementRealmResults = Equipement.getAllEquipements(realm);


    public static RealmResults<Equipement> getAllEquipements(Realm realm){

        return realm.where(Equipement.class).findAll();
    }

Comment: calling `equipementRealmResults.get(i)` will return a new instance of the proxy each time. Realm does not keep track of your `@Ignore`d field.

Comment: thanks for your answer, how can i store an not BDD data just for the execution time of the app in my extanded class RealmObject "Equipement" ?

Comment: I don't know what your data is and why it is ignored so I can't really comment.

Comment: I just wanted to put some data into a variable for the app execution time life in the Equipement class and reuse it later on the same object, but this is no possible . I will find an other way to do this. Thanks for your quick answer anyway , i better understand how realm works ^^